# Is it possible to change the timeout for ExternalEvaluate?

Tags: external-calls

I am using ExternalEvaluate in Mathematica 12.3.1.0 to do a computation with Jupyter and sagemath as kernel. Everything works fine if the computation finishes within 15 seconds, otherwise I get the error:

[image]

while the python process still runs until it is finished.

Looks like ExternalEvaluate waits only 15 seconds for a result? Is there no way to set the timeout to Infinity?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't reproduce the 15 second cutoff. For example `ExternalEvaluate["Python", "import time\ntime.sleep(25)\ntime.gmtime()"]` returns a result after 25 seconds for m

Comment: The Python example returns after 25 seconds for me as well. So this seems to be specific to external Jupyter sessions.